# Assigning value to JSON in PHP

Tags: php, json

I have to add json value from DB

```
$mysql_all_resultset = mysqli_query($con,  " SELECT drs.currentLatitude, drs.currentLongitude, dd.imei_number FROM device_owner_details dod, device_realtime_stats drs, device_details dd WHERE dod.name =  $name AND drs.deviceId = dod.deviceId AND dd.id = drs.deviceId ");

$rows_data = mysqli_fetch_row($mysql_all_resultset);

$device_details = array("imei_number" => $rows_data['imei_number'], "latitude" => $rows_data['currentLatitude'], "longitude" => $rows_data['currentLongitude']);


$response = json_encode($device_details);
```

It produce parse error, How to add the values to JSON

Comment: Can you post the error message.

Comment: Function calls from ajax so it produce  SyntaxError {stack: (...), message: "Unexpected token <"}

Answer (score 1):

Suround the `$name` with single quotes..

```
$mysql_all_resultset = mysqli_query($con,  " SELECT drs.currentLatitude, drs.currentLongitude, dd.imei_number FROM device_owner_details dod, device_realtime_stats drs, device_details dd WHERE dod.name =  '$name' AND drs.deviceId = dod.deviceId AND dd.id = drs.deviceId ");
```